# Pin 3D Object on a Place

Tags: android, augmented-reality, 3d-modelling

I'm using [AndAR](http://code.google.com/p/andar/) library, and to project 3d models there, you will use marker. My question is, how can do this following using this library.

1. project model on a marker
2. then I will have button to pin/tag it on a place.
3. After that, I will remove the marker, and the 3D objects should remain in the place that it is tag in.

Comment: A link to the library you're using would be useful.

Comment: @user1936227 The AndAR (Android Augmented Reality) pages contain AndARSampleProject2 and other examples, demonstrating the basic concepts. The current wording of your question is _very_ generic (i.e. "how do I write my program"), and in this form doesn't really fit the Q&A format well. Do you have any specific problems with using the library and/or following the example code?

Comment: I don't have any problem regarding with the library, I can now project models on  markers. But what I want to do is after the 3d object appears on the marker I want it to tag or pin it on a place. Now, my question is, is it possible to do that in the library that I'm using? If not, can some suggest a library..
Thank you..